# Using Windows 10 without motherboard drivers?

Tags: windows-10, windows-8, drivers, motherboard, windows-installation

My PC has Gigabyte 880 GMA UD2H Rev 1 or Rev 1.1 motherboard and I want to install Windows 10 on it.

The problem is the fact that the latest drivers made for my motherboard are for windows 8.1.

My uncle says I can use W8 drivers on W10 but it seems a little bit absurd.

In short can I use windows 10? I want to upgrade my rig to the best CPU and play games on DX12 on my IBM CRT.

Comment: W10 install should have the drivers for it, if not use windows update after W10 is installed to get drivers.

Comment: @duskwuff - What “Windows” games.  The author hasn’t even verified the drivers from the motherboard OEM are not applicable.  The author didn’t even indicate what device drivers they are trying to install.

Comment: @Ramhound the site for the motherboard has a drop down menu to choose windows version but W10 wasn't there. I currently lost the motherboard driver DVD it came with and net doesn't show any W10 drivers for it that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Practically speaking for most part it should just work - I'm running a 5 year old pc, and a 11 year old PC that run windows 10 nearly perfectly.

Windows *should* grab a sane set of basic drivers that should get the system functional

> My uncle says I can use W8 drivers on W10 but it seems a little bit absurd.

Its the same driver model. It should work. Presumably though, you wouldn't need it except for the CPU

> In short can I use windows 10? I want to upgrade my rig to the best CPU and play games on DX12 on my IBM CRT.

This should be fun, assuming you have a VGA port or a suitable adaptor 
- and might need a little more finagaling than the OS.

Answer (score 2):

Since there are no [Win10 drivers for your motherboard at the OEM site](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-880GM-UD2H-rev-10#support-dl-driver) and [no video driver for Win8](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-880GM-UD2H-rev-10#support-dl-driver-audio) there, either, I looked at the components, starting with the GPU, as you had specified you wanted [DirectX 12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectX#DirectX_12). DirectX 12 came out five years after that motherboard of yours did [(2010)](https://bit-tech.net/reviews/tech/motherboards/gigabyte-ga-880gma-ud2h-review/1/).

[According to AMD](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-rad-win-legacy), creators of the Radeon GPU on that board:

```
ATI Radeon™ HD 4000/ATI Mobility Radeon™ HD 4000, ATI Radeon™ HD 3000/ATI Mobility Radeon™ HD 3000, and ATI Radeon™ HD 2000/ATI Mobility Radeon™ HD 2000 Series Graphics reached peak performance optimization in October, 2013.

No additional driver releases are planned for these products.

The last operating system supported using the AMD drivers was Microsoft Windows® 8 with the AMD Catalyst 13.1 driver package, which can be downloaded from the AMD Driver page : [http://support.amd.com/en-us/download][6]

Driver support for these products under Windows® 8.1 and Windows® 10 is only available via Windows Update. **Please enable Windows Update to allow it to automatically detect and install display driver version 8.970.100.9001**
```

Therefore, if you want DirectX 12, you can install Windows 10 and see if it works, with <kbd>Win-R</kbd> CMD <kbd>Enter</kbd> dxdiag <kbd>Enter</kbd> If you don't have DirectX 12 after the Windows 10 install, and you *really* need it, try using the Windows 8 driver from AMD Support and play your game in Windows 8 compatibility mode. If that fails, you will need to install an add-in-card with a GPU which supports it; the [least spendy of which is $18](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=DirectX%2012%20video%20card&i=computers&s=price-asc-rank&qid=1559604242&ref=sr_st_price-asc-rank) at a large e-commerce site named after a river.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 has the best device support among all Windows versions,
so there is an excellent chance that it will work without any problem on
your motherboard.

If a driver is missing, and
if the Windows 8 driver installation via an executable file does not work,
click the `.exe` file, choose Properties, Compatibility tab,
tick "Run this program in compatibility mode for" and set the drop-down list
to "Windows 8", then run it.

If some device on the motherboard lacks a driver, search for a driver for that
specific device on the website of the manufacturer of the device
(not of the motherboard).